# Derivative of conditional expectation

Tags: statistics

I am completing exercises in Woolridge and am attempting the following:

Define $E(y|x)$ = $\delta_0 + \delta_1(x-u) + \delta_2(x-u)^2$ where $u=E(x)$

Show that, when averaged across the distribution of x: $$\frac{dE(y|x)}{dx}=\delta_1$$

I'm not really sure about this. My thought is:

$$\frac{dE(y|x)}{dx}=\delta_1 + 2\delta_2(x-u)$$

averaged across x, this is: 
$$\frac{n\delta_1}{n} + \frac{2\delta_2}{n}\sum\limits_{x}(x-u)$$

but since $u=E(x)$ we have that $\sum\limits_{x}(x-E(x)) = 0$

So $\frac{\delta_1n}{n} + 0 = \delta_1$

Is that roughly correct?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are basically asked to show that 
$$E_{x}\left[\frac{dE(y|x)}{dx} \right]=\delta_1.$$
After obtaining  the expression $$\frac{dE(y|x)}{dx}=\delta_1+2\delta_2(x−E(x))$$ 
take the expectation of both sides, use the fact that $\delta_2$ is constant and $E_{x}(x-E(x)))=0$.